# Is there an property value named invisible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead using of:

`if ( ! $('#XX').is(':visible) )`

Is there a value called `invisible` ? I tried that one , but doesn't work.

Thanks !

Comment: there isnt.....what's the problem with using visible..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
':hidden'

if ($('#XX').is(':hidden))
```

See the [jQuery doc for `:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

Answer (score 5):

There is a `.not()` function<strike>, that does the opposite to `.is()`:</strike>

```
.not(':visible')
```

http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: @alex: are you sure `:hidden` semantically equal to not-visible?

Comment: [Looks like it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L387). :P